Understanding the distinction between parametric and non-parametric density models in statistical manifolds
Consider a space of probability densities $\mathcal{M}_\mu$ on a measure space $(X, \mathcal{X}, \mu)$. My current understanding is:

A parametric model might be a Gaussian Mixture Model (GMM) with $k$ components:
$p(x) = \sum_{i=1}^k \pi_i \mathcal{N}(x; \mu_i, \sigma_i^2)$
where $\sum_{i=1}^k \pi_i = 1$, forming a finite-dimensional submanifold of $\mathcal{M}_\mu$.

An infinite GMM:
$p(x) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \pi_i \mathcal{N}(x; \mu_i, \sigma_i^2)$
where $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \pi_i = 1$, which seems to use the full infinite-dimensional space.

A non-parametric model, like Kernel Density Estimation:
$\hat{p}_h(x) = \frac{1}{nh} \sum_{i=1}^n K(\frac{x - x_i}{h})$
where $K$ is a kernel function and $h$ is a bandwidth parameter. Here also we generally takes the Kernal K as the Gaussian with say fixed covariance and mean as a parameter but I guess this is vary as per the data and there is no fixed number so that is why it is coming under the non parametric.


$\textbf{Questions:}$
Basically I am confused in what exactly the non-parametric density are? I mean does that means there must be a infinite number of parameter as in the case (2)? but it is countably infinite I guess. Or as in the case (3) where the parameters are not fixed and vary as per the data. Can someone explain to me intuitively!
